# Flutter app fails to connect to a flask server, how come?

Tags: android, flask, flutter

I have wrote a simple flutter app,
and when the user presses a button it initiates an http GET towards my flask server. here is the relevant flutter code:

```
Future <String> getData() async {
  http.Response resp =
      await http.get('http://192.168.1.10:5000/search?search=Hooray', headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  });

  if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = resp.body;
    var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
    print(decodedData);
    return decodedData;
  } else {
    int stCode = resp.statusCode;
    print('statusCode = $stCode');
    print(resp.reasonPhrase);
    return (resp.reasonPhrase);
  }
}

void performTasks() async {
  String res = await getData();
  print(res);
}
```

My flask server runs on my Linux box:

```
def main():
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I ran the flutter app on my android device but I keep getting:

> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out,
>   errno = 110, address = 192.168.1.10, port = 38466

BTW i have monitored the inbound traffic on my pc for inspecting incoming http get packets (the flask server runs on my pc), but those http GET packets never found there way to my pc.

Two more things to notice:

- If i wrap the getData() function with a simple flutter app and run it **on the pc** which runs the flask server, i get the expected response!
- The firewall was always inactive (ufw status is inactive)

Answer (score 1):

Simple issue.

You are trying to use `GET` request using your IP, which won't work.

I see you are running a `Flask` server on your localhost which can be directly accessed from your pc but not from outside. So, you get a timeout with your app.

**Solution**

You need to expose your localhost so that an external connection can be used.

Suggestions:

1. ngrok or
2. serveo.net

Basically they allow external traffic to your localhost port

**My testing.**

Running a `node` server using `express js` on port `3000` at my end.

But `http://<my_ip>:3000/` won't work from outside

So I ran the command `ssh -R test_user:80:localhost:3000 serveo.net` on a separate terminal which simply says that I want to expose my port `3000` and external connections will connect to `https://test_user.serveo.net`(it will give the URL after running the command for external connections).

Now my node server can see connections from my `localhost` (from my pc) and if someone visits `https://test_user.serveo.net`

For the flutter app

```
Future <String> getData() async {
  http.Response resp =
      await http.get('https://test_user.serveo.net', headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  });
  print(resp.body);
 //... whatever
}
```

will show you the response.

**EDIT:**

Another quick hack I found was this

type `ifconfig | grep inet` on your machine which will give you something like

```
 inet 192.168.12.1  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

you can also use `http://192.168.12.1` to connect from outside

Comment: Hi Doc, but i'm running everything inside my NAT, so i guess there is no need for ngrok. I accidentally just found out my wifi on my smartphone was turned off (Big Oooops) , what a foolish mistake! Coding late after midnight has it's consequences ;) oh boy!